One channel of Garage door remote intermittent
One channel of my Garage door remote has suddenly stopped working from any reasonable distance.

The other channel still works fine on a different opener.
The affected opener is unlocked; the remote still works if I get out of the car and get next to the closed door.
The remote battery is new.
The bulb in the opener is incandescent.
The antenna extends straight down and is unobstructed.

Thoughts?

The conductive coating on the button that's not working is probably worn.

reprogram it with garage opener

If the opener used to work from that channel from a reasonable distance but now only works at a near distance, the most likely explanation is that there is a new device using the same frequency.
Some explanations that I eliminated because it works on one channel but not the other:

A failure in the button itself.
A low battery.
A failure in the electronics.

Presumably any of those would make both channels not work.  They're reasonable guesses in general, but in your specific circumstance, I don't think they fit.
That it works up close but not far means that the programming didn't get lost.
More likely is that there is a conflicting device.  If it consistently doesn't work at distance, then that device is probably always on.  See if you can change the garage opener's channel to one without a conflict.  How to do that would be specific to the garage opener.  I don't have better advice than to check the manual or call the manufacturer.
Another possibility is that the receiver is failing.  I.e. not the remote end, but the opener end.  That would be specific to that channel.  You could check that with a second remote with the same channel programmed.

All or any of the issues addressed could explain the problem with your remote. But I'm thinking it may be something else. Recently I had someone who was having a similar problem with their remote not working at any distance from the garage. After some research I discovered that the problem was LED bulbs that had recently been installed just outside of the garage.
The issue, as I understand it, is that many LED bulbs emit radio frequencies that may interfere with some garage door openers. As soon as I changed out the LEDs the remote had the same range that it had previously.
If you have LED bulbs in the vicinity try replacing them with incandescent. There are some high quality LED bulbs that have low levels of frequency interference and might be okay.
Edit: Another solution is to change the frequency of the remote by adjusting the micro switches in the remote. You will have to then reprogram it to the opener. The fact that your other remote functions properly on a different frequency is convincing to me that LED lights are the problem.

Very Interesting!   Thanks for the info.
